# I would like to print the number which are divisible by 5 in python

Tags: python

Problem summary:

```
Input:
I have list which has any one the below inputs format,
    a=[21,23,20,98] # only one number divisible by 5
    a=[45,23,20,98] # More than one numbers divisible by 5
    a=[47,23,29,98] # None of the numbers divisible by 5

Expected result:

    a=[21,23,20,98] - it should only print the number -20
    a=[45,23,20,98] - it should only print the number -45,20
    a=[47,23,29,98] - it should print only once - Not found
```

The code i have tried:

```
Case 01: working for - only one number divisible by 5 or None of the numbers divisible by 5

for i in a:
    if i%5==0:
           print(i)
           break
else:
        print("not found")

Case 02: working for - More than one numbers divisible by 5

for i in a:
    if i%5==0:
           print(i)
```

I want the program in python, which should work for all three cases.

@Note

- Not found should print only once when None of the numbers divisible by 5

Comment: What problem are you having? What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving code in your way.

```
flag = True
for i in a:
    if i%5==0:
        print(i)
        flag = False

if flag:
    print("not found")
```

A better way is to use filter with lambda function:

```
a = [25, 3, 10, 5]
divisible_list = list(filter(lambda num: num%5==0, a))
if divisible_list:
    for ele in divisible_list:
       print(ele)
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for the input--- it is working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
L = [e for e in a if e%5==0]
if len(L) == 0:
   print("Not found")
else:
   print(*L, sep="\n")
```

Comment: Hi Thunder,  Thanks for the input--- it is working

Answer (score 0):

Using this function you can find the items in a list that are divisible by 5.

```
def divisibleByFive(a):
    b = [i for i in a if i % 5 == 0]
    if len(b) == 0:
        print("Not Found")
    else:
        print (b)
```

Here how to use it:

```
list1=[21,23,20,98] 
list2=[45,23,20,98] 
list3=[47,23,29,98]

divisibleByFive(list1)
divisibleByFive(list2)
divisibleByFive(list3)
```

Here is the output:

```
[20]
[45, 20]
Not Found
```

Comment: Hi qmorgan, Thanks for the input--- it is working